Identifying which PLSQL overloaded procedures get called
Consider the following code:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE the_package AS
   PROCEDURE procA ( pval1 IN VARCHAR2 );
   PROCEDURE procA ( pval1 IN NUMBER );
END;
/

The created a PLSQL package which has the overloaded procedures procA.
Now we create procedures that call these:
CREATE OR REPLACE testProc1 AS
  l_val VARCHAR2 := 'Boncho';
BEGIN
   the_package.procA( l_val );
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE testProc21 AS
  l_val NUMBER := 88;
BEGIN
   the_package.procA( l_val );
END;
/

What I want to do is to be able to identify which variants testProc1 and testProc2 call.
I cannot use DBA_DEPENDENCIES because it just tells me the testProc1 and testProc2 are dependent on the package the_package.
I cannot use DBA_PROCEDURES because it only tells me which procedures can be called.
It seems like the only option is to somehow use a combination of DBA_PROCEDURES, DBA_ARGUMENTS and DBA_SOURCE and do some compiler like analysis to get the desired output of:
Procedure testProc1 calls procA of package the_package at line 2.
Procedure testProc2 calls procA of package the_package at line 3.
But who wants to write a PLSQL compiler?
However I think that Oracle does the validation at compile time, i.e. when it compiles the procedures it checks that the procedures being called exist. So I am thinking perhaps there is information of precisely which procedure is called is stored in the meta data somewhere.
Does anyone know of anywhere in the meta data views where this information is kept?

ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL, STATEMENTS:ALL';

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE the_package AS
   PROCEDURE procA ( pval1 IN VARCHAR2 );
   PROCEDURE procA ( pval1 IN NUMBER );
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure testProc1 AS
  l_val VARCHAR2(100) := 'Boncho';
BEGIN
   the_package.procA( l_val );
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure testProc21 AS
  l_val NUMBER := 88;
BEGIN
   the_package.procA( l_val );
END;
/

select a.object_name, a.usage, b.object_name as called_object_name, b.name, b.line from
(select * From user_identifiers where name = 'PROCA' and usage in ('CALL')) a
join
(select * From user_identifiers where name = 'PROCA' and usage in ('DECLARATION')) b
on a.signature = b.signature
order by 1;

OBJECT_NAME          USAGE       CALLED_OBJECT_NAME   NAME             LINE
-------------------- ----------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
TESTPROC1            CALL        THE_PACKAGE          PROCA               2
TESTPROC21           CALL        THE_PACKAGE          PROCA               3


Wow. Brilliant! A question though, what affect does the ALTER SESSION have - is it to tell Oracle to gather more info when the objects are compiled? What if the PLSQL objects already exist, i.e I cannot recompile them?

@ProWest Yes, it instructs Oracle to collect extra information for code analysis. Without setting PLSCOPE_SETTINGS the PLSCOPE dictionary tables are not populated. If the objects already exist, you can simply recompile them after setting the above to have this kind of information about them.

OK. I would think though that even without setting those flags the PLSQL compiler must resolve the references fully, so maybe it stores this info in some v$ or x$ view anyway but only exposes  them to these dba/all/.user views when the flags are set.
